# Meteor.users.findOne возвращает undefined

Tags: meteor

Использую Meteor. Документ user имеет следующий вид:

```
{
   "_id" : "jochnuekhmdNej8KY",
   ...
   "profile" : {
       "username" : "ivan",
       "age": 25,
   },
   ...
}
```

Хочу найти пользователя по параметру profile.username

```
var username = "ivan";
var user = Meteor.users.findOne({profile: {username: username}});
console.log(user);
```

В итоге возвращает undefined

В чем причина?

Answer (score 1):

Стоит попробовать вот  так `Meteor.users.findOne({"profile.username": username});`

Comment: Спасибо ) Все работает !